# How do I do a tp rotation in minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Please help I never get my head rotated only body

Comment: Are you talking about the `tp [target player] <x> <y> <z> [<y-rot> <x-rot>]` command? Because I believe that should rotate your head as well as body. Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: /tp @a -179 31 -29 rx=-90 ry=0

Comment: This is in a command block

Answer (score 1):

Use the y-rot and x-rot arguments in /tp

```
/tp <target player> <x> <y> <z> [<y-rot> <x-rot>]
```

Do not include either the <>s or the []s when executing a command

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp)

Comment: That doesn't work it just tps me in the way i pressed the button

Comment: this is what i put /tp @a -179 31 -29 [rx=-90,ry=0]

Comment: the [] are meant to be removed

Comment: [] means the arguments are optional, <> means they are mandatory. both [] and <> need to be removed when using a command

Comment: /tp @a -179 31 -29 rx=-90 ry=0 that's what I got and it still doesnt work

Comment: This is in a command block

Comment: @dogecat `/tp @a -179 31 -29 -90 0` You don't need the `rx=` or `ry=`

Comment: Doesnt work only tps me

Comment: @dogecat Who else are you expecting it to teleport? The @a should target every player on the server.

Comment: ok i tried it in single player, it works. Its my server and Idk what to do :(

Comment: @dogecat if it's bukkit, see if any of your plugins overwrite the vanilla tp command (Essentials or whatnot). They tend to do that sometimes.

Comment: try only positive numbers:
360-90 = 270 instead of -90